# Window is being skipped when alt-tabbing

Tags: windows, alt-tab

I frequently alt tab between two windows with other windows running in the background. When I hold alt, then press and release tab, the windows should look like the numbers below, where windows 1 and 2 are the windows I am currently using, and 3 and 4 are background windows. The bolded number indicates the window is being selected:

1 **2** 3 4

2 **1** 3 4

1 **2** 3 4

2 **1** 3 4

That is, I should be switching between windows 1 and 2 only

However, occasionally, the windows get shown as below:

1 2 **3** 4

As in, the 2nd window was skipped over and the 3rd window was directly selected. I have tested with multiple different applications as windows 1 and 2, and I have not found a pattern as to when this bug occurs.

This issue only started recently, and I suspect that it may be related to the recent "alt tab to show edge tabs" Windows update.

Has anyone experienced the same problem, and are there any solutions?

Edit: current OS build is 19042.630, Alt-tab to show tabs in Edge is off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alt-Tab is currently bugged in Windows 10 20H2, even if you disable the Edge Tabbing, it will alt-tab you to a window you didn't want to. You can go back to the legacy alt-tab while waiting for a fix from Microsoft. Here's a howto:

- Regedit Path: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`
- Create DWORD (32 bit) `AltTabSettings`
- Change value of `AltTabSettings` to "1"